# Integrate equation. Variable in terms of another

Tags: equation-solving

This might have an easy solution but I am new in Mathematica. I have an equation for which I want to find the solution. My equation goes like:

$$\frac{dr}{dx} = \frac{r}{x}\cdot\frac{2}{k\,a^{-2}\,g\,x^4\,r^{g+1}-1}.$$

What I was trying to do to solve it was to use Integrate. However I am not quite sure if this will work, also I am wondering if I have to say that r is function of x? So the equation looks like:

$$\frac{dr(x)}{dx}=\frac{r(x)}{x}\cdot\frac{2}{k\,a^{-2}\,g\,x^4\,r(x)^{g+1}-1}.$$

But if I do so, then it multiplies $r\cdot x$.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: To obtain more useful responses, please include in your question your actual code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation you appear to be trying to solve is

```
eq = D[r[x], x] == r[x]/x*(2/(k*a^-2*g*x^4*r[x]^(g + 1) - 1))
```

It is necessary to indicate that `r` is a function of `x`.  Then,

```
sol = DSolve[eq, r[x], x]
```

gives an implicit equation for `r[x]`.

```
(* Solve[(2*Log[r[x] - g*r[x]])/(1 - g) + 
   (-4*Log[x] + Log[a^2*(-1 + g) + 2*g*k*x^4*r[x]^(1 + g)])/(-1 + g) == C[1], r[x]] *)
```

Is this what you had in mind?

**Addendum**

If desired, the equation for `r[x]` can be extracted and simplified as follows:

```
Exp[Simplify[sol[[1, 1]] (1 - g)]] == Exp[sol[[1, 2]] (1 - g)]

(* ((-1 + g)^2*x^4*r[x]^2)/(a^2*(-1 + g) + 2*g*k*x^4*r[x]^(1 + g)) == E^((1 - g)*C[1]) *)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, yes, that is what I wanted to solve it for r[x]. I have a question, what is exactly what the Exp does? Well I understand that you are taking the exponential to write the equation in simple terms, instead of log, but I don't understand the last part: Exp[sol[[1, 2]] (1 - g)]

Comment: As I performed simplifications of the left side of the equation inside `Solve`, I did the same on the right side, namely `C[1]`.  of course, `C[1]` is an arbitrary constant, so making transformations involving it is a nicety.